# How to get information from multiple tables in database with single id?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 8 tables in my database, I want to get their data from database using query,.

My first table has `master_id` and I have passed it in my every table after master table. I want to fetch all data with `master_id` that I have passed in my tables.

I got some syntax errors in it.

```
SELECT edu_tb.* FROM edu_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = edu_tb.`master_id`

AND
    // table 2 experience

SELECT exp_tb.* FROM exp_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = exp_tb.`master_id`

AND
// table 3 certificate

SELECT certi_tb.* FROM exp_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = certi_tb.`master_id`
```

Comment: this sql syntax is basically wrong. to get a basic idea, let us know what you want to accomplish with the data. like are just trying new queries in the php-myadmin or you are implementing it in your software code?

Comment: There is an obvious syntax error in your 'third query' - you are retrieving certi_tb.*, but from exp_tb, not from certi_tb.

Comment: I will implement in my software code but first i want to get using the data from my tables, just to clear my ideas

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use * to retrieve fields from a query, especially when multiple tables are involved. The query below probably will be problematic because of the asterisks.

```
SELECT edu_tb.*, exp_tb.*, certi_tb.*
FROM master_tb
INNER JOIN edu_tb ON edu_tb.`master_id` = master_tb.`master_id`
INNER JOIN exp_tb ON exp_tb.`master_id` = master_tb.`master_id'
INNER JOIN certi_tb ON certi_tb.`master_id` = master_tb.`master_id
```

Comment: this is opposite use, master_id is passed in each table

Comment: edu_id,exp_id,certi_tb is not used in master_tb.

Comment: @SunnySagar: The order of the tables in the 'from' clause doesn't matter. I chose to write 'from master_tb' as all of the other tables have a foreign key which matches this table's primary key. I could just have easily have written 'select ... from edu_tb inner join ...' and then you would have said that there is no link between edu_tb and exp_tb.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of:

```
SELECT * FROM master_tb mt
INNER JOIN edu_tb et  ON mt.master_id = et.master_id
INNER JOIN exp_tb  ex_t ON mt.master_id = ex_t.master_id
INNER JOIN certi_tb ct ON mt.master_id = ct.master_id;
```

Comment: there is runnig but get nothing in tables

Answer (score 0):

To get a result in the phpmyadmin,

```
SELECT edu_tb.* FROM edu_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = edu_tb.`master_id`

--AND
-- table 2 experience

SELECT exp_tb.* FROM exp_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = exp_tb.`master_id`

--AND
--table 3 certificate

SELECT certi_tb.* FROM certi_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = certi_tb.`master_id`
```

This query results in `3 different table outputs` on the myadmin query result are.

If you are trying to get a data-set into **php code**, **the output of only one select statement will be received by php**(the output of the last select statement).

So joining all this tables together would get you all this tables included in a single select statement.

```
SELECT * FROM edu_tb
INNER JOIN master_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = edu_tb.`master_id`

INNER JOIN exp_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = exp_tb.`master_id`

INNER JOIN certi_tb ON
master_tb.`master_id` = certi_tb.`master_id`
```

hope this helps.

Comment: got no any error but data is not showing from tables

Comment: the first one or second?